# issue while using switch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4, uiswitch

I have two view controllers and nibs. I populated one view controller with a toggle switch and declared this in its header file:

```
@public UISwitch *toggleSwitch;
```

and exposed it as a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *toggleSwitch;
```

I also connected the switch with `toggleSwitch` outlet. Then I used this switch in my other view controller like this :

```
theViewControllerWhereIDeclaredTheSwitch.toggleSwitch.on = YES;
```

Though everything worked fine with the switch being ON by default but when I switched off the switch it threw an exception: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" in the main.m file. I get this error quite often while working with Xcode, this error is a real pain in my ass. Please help.

Comment: You are probably having some issues because objects have been released already. It also makes not much sense to let viewcontroller-2 change the state of the views belonging to viewcontroller-1, this defeats the purpose of having separate view controllers. You probably want to tell viewcontroller-1 only about logical program state (using some kind of a model) and let viewcontroller-1 figure out if it should toggle the switch when it's view gets loaded again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not share UI elements over multiple `UIViewControllers`.

A better approach would be to share a `BOOL` or even encapsulate the state in your own object inheriting from `NSObject` and pass that between the 2 `UIViewControllers`.

Answer (score 1):

@werner is right.

When programming a Controller and a View associated, you are implementing the NVC Pattern.
The idea is that you have this Controller object that is the brain between a View and a Model that holds datas.
Hence what you should perform in your application is not share the switch state but update a BOOL value in your Model when triggering the switch and share the Model with the two Controllers in order to know the value in the two Controllers.

(CF: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))